# some features of my website is not working on localhost

Tags: html, css, caching, xampp

My HTML file is working perfectly while I am using its path

`file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/resume/dashboard/ads.html` to run it, but while I'm running it via localhost

`http://localhost/resume/dashboard/ads.html`
from the same location, some of its features like:

(modal scrolling and js code) are not working.

Please help!

ads.html

```
   <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="assets/img/apple-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="../img/logo/kk.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.7.0/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />

    <title>Ads</title>

    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport' />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />


    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS     -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Animation library for notifications   -->
    <link href="assets/css/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <!--  Paper Dashboard core CSS    -->
    <link href="assets/css/paper-dashboard.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <!--  CSS for Demo Purpose, don't include it in your project     -->
    <link href="assets/css/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!--  Fonts and icons     -->
    <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/latest/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="assets/css/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>



<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-1">
  Launch Modal 1
</button>  

<div class="modal fade" id="modal-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Modal 1</p>

  <a href="#modal-2" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Next ></a>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->  



  <!-- #modal 2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-2">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">

  <a href="#modal-1" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">< Previous</a>
        <p>Modal .Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus dolor auctor. Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et. Donec sed odio dui. Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla..2</p>


      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->  




</body>
    <script></script>
    <!--   Core JS Files   -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!--  Checkbox, Radio & Switch Plugins -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-checkbox-radio.js"></script>

    <!--  Charts Plugin -->
    <script src="assets/js/chartist.min.js"></script>

    <!--  Notifications Plugin    -->
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-notify.js"></script>

    <!--  Google Maps Plugin    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <!-- Paper Dashboard Core javascript and methods for Demo purpose -->
    <script src="assets/js/paper-dashboard.js"></script>

    <!-- Paper Dashboard DEMO methods, don't include it in your project! -->
    <script src="assets/js/demo.js"></script>



</html>
```

bootstrap.min.css

```
 #modal-2 {
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```

In this section of code, the second modal is not scrolling.

Comment: We'd need the relevant sections of your code for that. Most likely including css and js files does not work.

Comment: You should be able to see the reason in your http servers error log file. That always is the first location to look at when implementing in a web environment...

Comment: Please check your all path of javascript & CSS while load your HTML file over http://localhost

If you got 404 error while load JS & CSS it means there is a problem with your path

once you correct it will work !

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B__0Y7-xIaLVYVhrYzdORHdpT2s/view?usp=sharing  here is the link to my code

Comment: @MamtaKumari Please do _not_ post links to arbitrary sites, those links will stop working in future. That leaves broken questions. Instead _always_ post the relevant sections of the code _inline_ in the question and, very important, _answer to questions and hints_! So: what _do_ you see in your http servers error log file? Assuming that you _did_ take a look into it after you were told to?

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for your suggestion, and can you tell me please where can I find HTTP servers error log file?

Comment: That is configured in your http servers configuration. On unixoid systems that is something like `/var/log/apache2/error.log` or similar, not sure where that might be found on MS-Windows based systems. You are looking for the `ErrorLog` directive...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, just the CSS files get cached, it's a very common problem for new web developers. So, to get rid of it just clear your cache from your web browser or just press cmd+shift+R. If you think that you have written right CSS but it's not visible in your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely problem is that you are using incorrect paths. When you move from file based to http based the root / folder is your webroot, when using the file:// approach the root folder is the root of the drive the files are hosted on.

Comment: This is a _guess_, not an answer. So it should have been a comment.

Comment: @arkascha, yes, my apologies, you may be right. It is an educated guess though, most issues I have seen moving from file based testing to http based testing are the result of the paths to files being different

Comment: Sure, you are absolutely right there. I made my comment since we all are often lead to these conclusions which _usually_ are pointing into the right direction. But I also often saw that the actual issue was something completely different which is why I prefer to _first_ ask for details or make a suggestion where to look and only to _answer_ the question if I _know_ the answer is correct and indeed _does_ solve the issue.

Comment: @GlenBee, no that is not the problem. All the paths are correct and working fine in some other folder but it is not working in a particular folder

Answer (score 0):

When web sites work in one form and not another, it is typically due to one of two things:

1. A path or paths to various resources are fixed and not relative. For example: maybe your HTML looks for a Java Script file in a path called C:/xampp/htdocs/resume/dashboard/javascript/myjs.js instead of a relative path like ./javascript/myjs.js or maybe, you are already using relative paths but the starting directory of the relative path is off.
   Usually you would notice this by images not showing or Java Script files not loading.
2. When you run as localhost, you are in the localhost domain and if you're making requests to other domains maybe they are being stopped for security reasons. You will generally notice these types of errors if you open the developer console in your browser you'd see errors saying that a resource was not allowed to load for security reasons or a cross-domain request was blocked.

If it is ONLY some Java Script not working, then I'd look at what attributes those javascript share... if they share a path take extra care to validate those, or if they require jQuery then you might need to load JQuery from the web instead of loading it locally.

**To start your diagnostics**, I'd recommend, opening the developer console in your browser (Chrome: right-click on a page and pick "Inspect" and look in the console tab) Take a look at the errors it shows. (usually a yellow triangle or red stop sign followed by a semi-descriptive error) It should tell you what is not loading and why and work backward from there.

If your paths are accurate and you're still stuck, you might look at the DocumentRoot setting in C:\xampp\apache\conf\httpd.conf and make sure that is set to the right starting directory, but check your errors first before altering configs. Changing configs should be a last resort... and if you do change them keep a backup of the original!

Comment: It is not working only in a particular folder.. when I have copied the HTML and the assets in some other folder in htdocs it is working fine. but when I'm pasting the same file in my project folder, then only its not working.

Comment: I have already checked all the paths and developer console but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: What is the folder path that is not working?  Would it happen to have a space or other unusual character in the path name?